# Как сделать что бы бот в дискорде переходил по Link ссылке(сокращенной)?

Tags: python, discord.py

Мне надо написать бота для дискорд который будет переходить по линк ссылке, уже весь интернет облазил, но нигде нет такой информации, помогите найти выход пж.
[example](https://example.com) - вот это пример линк ссылки

Это пример что пишет бот, а программа должна распознавать и переходить по ссылке
(Я знаю как открывать ссылку в браузере, мне надо именно обрабатывать это сообщение)
[image]

Comment: _"Link ссылка"_? Это что-то новое :D Разве ссылка приходит _"сокращённой"_? Мне кажется, что это просто форматирование не стороне клиента. Уточните, какое сообщение Вам приходит на сервер?

Comment: грубо говоря да, именно с сокращенной ссылкой, но я не могу понять какой тип сообщение отсылает бот и как мне расшифровать зашифрованную ссылку

Answer (score 2):

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
   emb = discord.Embed(title = "Hello", description="[[Название сообщение например тык(тут ссылка)]
```

Поздно увидел вашу запись

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]